# Max-height and nanoscroller + AngularJS NgRepeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, nanoscroller

I'm trying to make a div that expands to a `max-height` using nanoScroller and ngrepeat of angularjs, but I can't make it work, here is the plunkr: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/M75vQ82G4WFC6pYSy1Q1?p=preview).

If you change the `_Array` length to `5` you will see what I am saying. The height of the div doesn't adjust to the content... it stays at `max-height` when it should be shrinking to fit.

**Here is the HTML code:**

```
<div id="console" ng-app="myApp">
  <header>Title Here</header>
  <section>
    <ul ng-init="(_Array = []).length = 15;" class="nano">
      <div class="nano-content">
        <li ng-repeat="i in _Array track by $index" post-render="">{{ $index }}</li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

**and the directive to use nanoScroller:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('postRender', postRender);

postRender.$inject = ['$timeout'];

function postRender($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            $timeout(function () {
                jQuery('.nano').nanoScroller({
                    preventPageScrolling: true
                })
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

**and my SCSS:**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
#console {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 330px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: #FFF;

    header {
        padding: 15px;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.8);
    }

    section {
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: #333;
        height: 100%;

        ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            & div {
                padding: 15px 15px;
            }
            li {
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: red;
                padding: 15px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using min-height

Comment: Where? i try in all sites but it doesn't work, can you try it in plunkr? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your nanoScroller code is placing your content in an absolutely positioned `div`. This means that your entire unordered list is out of the flow of content and will not fill/expand the height of the parent.

You can fix it by removing `position: absolute;` from the scrollable container and moving the `max-height` declaration to it. So for instance:

```
.nano>.nano-content {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

You will then also have to remove `height: 100%;` from the parent container.

[Here your adjusted plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dWkN1IKk2FbR7IERNvPa?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your styles with this

```
#console {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px; 
  width: 330px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: #FFF;
}
#console section ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```